# Power set of a set of graphs (including a null graph).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, cardinals

Suppose $G$ is a complete graph with two vertices, then the number of all possible sub graphs of $G$ is $5$.  Let the set of those sub graphs  be denoted by $S=\lbrace \langle \emptyset,  \emptyset\rangle, G_1, G_2, G_3, G\rbrace$, where $\langle \emptyset,  \emptyset\rangle$ is a null graph. If $P( S)$  is a power set of $S$, then will it be true that

> $|P(S)|=2^5$?

I know that it is true for a set in general,  but here, i have a little confusion only for the reason that $S$ contains a null graph.

Comment: Yes, it's $25$.  The null graph creates no difficulty.

Comment: @saulspatz Ok. I got it. Thanks a lot. Hope you mean  $2^5$??